# VERITAS Backup Exec does not accept tapes

Tags: backupexec, tape, tapedrive, veritas

VERITAS Backup Exec 8.60 Rv 3878 does not accept brand new Sony SDX3-100C tapes using a Compaq AIT 50 GB tape drive.

I want to introduce new tapes to an ancient backup system as described above on a Windows 2k machine.

I tried the "Inventory" and "Label" commands. No luck.

The former results in the following error message:

```
Job started: Montag, 25. November 2013 at 12:36:40
Job type: Inventory
Job Log: DevJb010.txt
Device name: COMPAQ 1
=====================================================================


----- TapeAlert Events -----


Information
Device:
You have tried to load a cartridge of a type which is not supported by this drive.


Warning
Device:
The memory in the tape cartridge has failed, which reduces performance.
Do not use the cartridge for further backup operations.
Slot   1: Bad media


======================================================================
Job ended: Montag, 25. November 2013 at 12:44:20
Job completion status: Failed
```

The strange thing is there currently **are** tapes of that type in use.

- How do I make Backup Exec use those Sony tapes?
- What to do to the Sony tapes to have Backup Exec accept them?

Comment: Is it possible that the specific tapes have failed as the error reports?

Comment: @DaveM: I observed this behaviour for two different brand-new-just-out-of-the-box tapes.

Comment: Thanks.  I have had a very similar issue with some Imation tapes.  Fresh box of 10 and six were defective.  Much head scratching and testing before they were confirmed defective after a return to their facility and a six week wait

Comment: Wow...did you save this question from 2001 just to post it today?

Comment: @TheCleaner: If I had, would I get a badge for it? *harharhar* Btw: Even back in 2001 I thought I'm done with tapes.

Comment: Sorry mate, I was blown away by the words Compaq, Veritas, 8.6, etc.  YES, you should get a badge for this, as should anyone that knows the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was that the "Compaq AIT 50 GB tape drive" simply does not seem to be able to handle those "double" capacity tapes "Sony SDX3-100C".

Comment: So when you said there ARE tapes of that type in use, you misspoke?  Glad you figured it out!  Sorry you still use tape. :)

Comment: Yes, climbing down myself into the bunker revealed only "SD2 50"-something-alike tapes were in use as opposed to the statement the (poor) guy made who changes such tapes every day.